# Array por parametro swift

Tags: swift

Boa tarde pessoal tudo bem?

como eu faço para passar um array por parametro? e gostaria que o parametro do array seja opcional

Exemplo:

```
func startGame(teste: Array) -> String {


    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordHard.count)))
    let word = wordHard[randomIndex]

    // verificando se existe palavra atribuida a variavel
    if currentWord == "" {
        currentWord = word
        infoHelp.text = wordHardHelp[randomIndex]
    }
    return word
}
```

Obrigado amigos!

Comment: Suas funções deveriam ser nomeadas começando com uma letra minúscula.

Comment: Você precisa passar o tipo do array `func startGame(teste: [String]?) -> String {`

Comment: Continuo com erro no parametro

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta e coloca o seu código e o erro que tá dando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para passar um `array`, basta você colocar o tipo dele, caso opcional adicione `?`

```
func startGame(teste: [Int]?) -> String {


    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordHard.count)))
    let word = wordHard[randomIndex]

    // verificando se existe palavra atribuida a variavel
    if currentWord == "" {
        currentWord = word
        infoHelp.text = wordHardHelp[randomIndex]
    }
    return word
}
```

Comment: passar um parâmetro para uma função ou método sem sequer utilizar ele não faz o menor sentido

Comment: Percebi isso, mas acho que foi apenas para aprendizado dele, vai saber ...